# Big Data transfer between different systems

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

We have different set of data into different systems like Hadoop, Cassandra, MongoDB. But our analytic team want to get the stitched data from different systems. For example customer information with demographic will be in one system, their transactions will be in another system. Analytic should able to query to get data like from US users what was the volume of transaction. We need to develop an application to provide ease way to interact with different system. What is the best way to do?

Another requirement:
If we want to provide their custom workspace in a system like MongoDB, they can easily place with it. What is the best strategy to pull data from one system to another system on demand?

Any pointer or common architecture used to solve this kind of problem will be really helpful.

Comment: Is there any major advantage of this approach?I mean, why would you store the related data in different systems?

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions here:

1. How can I consolidate data from different systems into one system?
2. How can I create some data in Mongo for people to experiment with?

Here we go ... =)

1. I would pick *one* system and target that for consolidation. In other words, between Hadoop, Cassandra and MongoDB, which one does your team have the most experience with? Which one do you find easiest to query with? Which one do you have set up to scale well?

   Each one has pros and cons to scale, storage and queryability.

   I would pick one and then pump all data to that system. At a recent job, that ended up being MongoDB. It was easy to move data to Mongo and it had by far the best query language. It also had a great community and setting up nodes was easier than Hadoop, etc.
2. Once you have solved (1), you can *trim* your data set and create a scaled down sandbox for people to run ad-hoc queries against. That would be my approach. You don't want to support the entire data set, because it would likely be too expensive and complicated.

   If you were doing this in a relational database, I would say just run a

   `select top 1000 * from [table]`

   query on each table and use that data for people to play with.